# spikes in the cost vs iteration graph using ReLU activation function

Tags: neural-network

The cost vs iteration graph while using the ReLU activation function has number of spikes

[image: ReLU activation function]

The accuracy on MNIST dataset (both train and test) is around 95%, also on using sigmoid as an activation function I get a smooth downward sloping curve so I think the implementation is correct. Are these spikes expected for ReLU? How would you explain this property?

Comment: @Mike, you use Stochastic gradient descent? And do you take your mini batches randomly? How much is the "amount of training samples" divided by the "mini batch size"? Regularity means that the same effect probably happens every time arriving at a batch containing some 'difficult' samples. Samples which are difficult to recognize.

Comment: It seems that you frequently overshoot after descending in the direction of the basin. Try adaptively reducing your step size. Also keep track of your validation set cost; that's what you really want to reduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run my implementation of MNIST digit recognition I even get those spikes for a sigmoid transfer function. You have to question yourself: how bad are those spikes? I presume you use stochastic gradient descent right. For every iteration you consider a batch (a subspace of the samples) and train on that. Some of those batches contain very difficult pictures and your network will fail at them, resulting in a high cost. This in turn will lead to a temporary high adaptations of your weights and biases. You see that it drops again quite quickly because the other samples will again send it in the right direction.

I think you have more spikes because your ReLU is just better at generalization and thus after a while you will get more peaks (but lower) because the network gets better and better. And in the end the most important criteria is your accuracy and not the cost ;). This has less problems with the spikes because it takes into account all the samples instead of a batch.

Concluding: stochastic gradient descent will go to a low point, but because of it random walk it might bump into some peaks, but in the end it will find a nice low cost.

If you still have some questions, feel free to ask, I am still quite new here and still have to learn how to give good answers.

Comment: Your answer makes things clear. Is gradient clipping helpful in handling these spikes?

Comment: I think you should experiment with it, but I do think it might help. If your algorithm passes very difficult samples, it will want to adapt its weights and biases a lot (even if it is not really desired). If you clip the gradient, these effects will be reduced. At the same time it might make your algorithm slower, but you had a lot of spikes so I think on average you gain an advantage! Good luck with your coding.